# Lotus Notes NotesSQL ODBC driver read-only

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have been asked to retrieve and update data remotely to our Lotus Notes database.
I installed the Lotus Notes NotesSQL ODBC driver on my 64 windows 7 PC.  I can read data from a Notes view just fine however when I try to update a field I get a message stating the that the Recordset is not updateable.

Does anyone know what would cause the data to be read-only?

Can a Notes view be set as read-only?
Could it be that I have a 64 bit OS and the driver is 32 bit (I believe)?
Has anyone else seen this?

Note.  I am using MS Access to view data.

Comment: I did go back and look at the views returned using the ODBC driver.  I found out one of the views was a "Document".  When I linked to the Document I found out that I was able to write to the Document.  It appears the trick is to know what items are views and what items are documents.

Comment: That's correct. Whilst a Notes view can look like a table to the untrained eye, it is not. Notes is not a relational database, rather a document database ("No SQL" if you will!) A view is a report on underlying data. Rather than those data being stored in rows within a table, they are stored in documents, which are "selected" by a view. So as have found out, it's the underlying documents you need to update, not the view (which is basically a report-cum-index).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes views are read-only by nature.  I don't have much experience with making updates via NotesSQL, but you might see if you can connect to a "Notes Form" instead and make a change.  Other than that, I'd make sure the Notes account you're using to connect has the appropriate access to the database.